# Unable to update packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, wine, ppa

I have tried to do apt-get update in my ubuntu system and has got the following error:

Please help

```
Hit:17 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done                                                  

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please follow recommendations for code blocks on this [link](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)... I've edited yours

Answer (score 0):

that repository does not have an artful release. the newest version in that repo is Xenial.

Comment: What could be the fix?

Comment: you could try using the Xenial version. other than that there is no fix. or did you want to remove that repo?